# How can I include a .pch for a specific pod, in cocoapods?

Tags: cocoapods

In my projet `MyProject` (I'm using `cocoapods`), I want to use `MyPod`.

The classes of `MyPod` are copied to `MyProject`, but not the `.pch`. Hence, the project is not compiling.

So, I have two questions :

1. How can I add the `.pch` of `MyPod` to the imported classes of `MyPod`?
2. Is there a way to "include" the `.pch` of `MyPod` in the `.pch` of `MyProject` (or, to "modify" the latter)

I am sure 1. is possible. I am learning `cocoapods` right now.

---

EDIT

As said in the [documentation](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#prefix_header_contents) of cocoapods, the `prefix_header_contents` attribute of a `.podspec` is "not recommended as Pods should not pollute the prefix header of other libraries or of the user project."

So, is there any other way? **Are we supposed to develop libraries without anything in the `.pch`?**

Comment: Any updates or workarounds on this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to use the following property:

```
s.prefix_header_contents
```

For instance:   `s.prefix_header_contents = '#import "SomeClass.h"'`.

It will add this line of code to the `pch` file associated to the Pod.

Comment: `prefix_header_file` is another option http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#prefix_header_file